# Copy part request to model

Tags: php, laravel

I have request:

```
 +request: ParameterBag {#43 ▼
    #parameters: array:9 [▼
      "fam" => "tr"
      "im" => "fd"
      "ot" => "ffff"
      "phone" => "ва"
      "log" => "44"
      "log2" => "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
      "pass" => "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
      "Регистрация" => null
      "_token" => "T2eaYlfdTtWoAsAivf06UegUxCknxahR6jRQOyd4"
    ]
  }
```

Function:

```
public function UserChange2(Request $request){
    dump($request);
    $data=$request->all();
    $log = $request->input('log');
    dump($log);
    $user=userModel::select(['fam','im','ot','phone','log','pass'])->where('log',$log)->first();
    dump($user);
    $user->fill($request->all())->save();
    dump($user);
    $user->save;
}
```

User model.

```
 class userModel extends Model
    {
        public $timestamps = false;
        protected $fillable=['fam','im','ot','phone','log','pass','reg','token','date','position'];

    }
```

But a can not  `$user->fill($request->all())->save()` because in my request there are content 'log2' (for search user in database).
How I can serarch and update model?

Comment: Are you getting any error? log2 is not in the fillable list so it shouldn't break anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit curious on why the variable is there if you don't wish to persist its new value into the database, anyway here is how you can make laravel ignore this extra variable - by using `except()`. Instead of using `all()` use `except()` that way you can filter out the unwanted parameter returning everything else.

```
public function UserChange2(Request $request){
  $data = $request->all();
  $log = $request->input('log');
  $user=userModel::select(['fam','im','ot','phone','log','pass'])->where('log',$log)->first();
  $user->fill($request->except('log2'))->save();
  dump($user);
  $user->save;
}
```

If you happen to have more that one variable to ignore you can add them in array `except(['log2', 'log3','log4'])`

Comment: But now " Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' "

Comment: Which column did you define as primary key in table?